# Why is php zip extension not working on ubuntu though it's installed?

Tags: php, zip, apache2, ubuntu-16.04

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm trying to install prestashop e-commerce CMS that requires php zip extension to unzip the main CMS folder.

I have installed php-zip and php7.2-zip and I also restarted the web server (apache2) but the CMS still displays the following message

```
An error has occured:
You must install PHP zip extension first
```

Here's the result of my installed php zip packages and my current php version:

```
eljaouhari@eljaouhari-HP-350-G1:/var/www/html$ php -v
PHP 7.2.5-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: May  5 2018 04:59:13) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.2.5-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies


eljaouhari@eljaouhari-HP-350-G1:/var/www/html$ apt list --installed | grep php | grep zip

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

php-zip/xenial,xenial,now 1:7.2+60+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 all   [installé]
php7.2-zip/xenial,now 7.2.5-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64  [installé]
```

I spent an hour and a half trying to figure out whether I need to activate the extestion on the php.ini file and also installing and reinstalling and restarting the web server but nothing seems to work.

I have tried a few solutions on the web that used to work for me but I can't seem to find a good solution.

Please help me with your experience!

Comment: Did you activate the extension in php.ini?

Comment: Exactly ! I can't find a single line containing the "zip" word. If it must be activated on the php.ini ile I must not be knowing which extension name it has. Thanks

Comment: On Ubuntu you can try to run `sudo phpenmod -v ALL -s ALL zip` *(and then restart the server)*.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution after I printed the results of the phpinfo() function.

It seems that the version of php printed with the "php -v" command is not the version that actually apache is using. Apache ended up using the 7.0 version.

Thanks everyone.